# Is there MicrosoftMvcAjax client library reference/documentation anywhere?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

There is an good reference for their "traditional" Ajax client library [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397536.aspx). But I cannot find any references to their MVC client library (usually contained in MicrosoftMvcAjax.js script which is included in MVC2 project template). Does it exist at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MsAjaxMvc was only an intermediate library which currently only exists for down-level-compatibility to MVC 2.0. I would recommend you to use jQuery which is the default lib in MVC 3.0 and higher.